# Moving checkmarks in checkbox lists after page reload - Firefox only

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, checkbox

I'm getting some strange behavior in Firefox whenever I put checkboxes inside a list (ol, ul, dl), and then dynamically insert buttons above the list. If I start with a something simple list like this:

```
<dl class="c">
    <dt><label for="a1"><input type="checkbox" id="a1" />one</label></dt>
    <dt><label for="a2"><input type="checkbox" id="a2" />two</label></dt>
    <dt><label for="a3"><input type="checkbox" id="a3" />three</label></dt>
</dl>
```

and add some jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = $('<button type="button">a</button>');
    var b = $('<button type="button">b</button>');
    $('<div/>').append(a).append(b).insertBefore($('.c'));
});
```

...then open it in Firefox, it looks fine at first. **But check the first checkbox, reload the page, and the check-mark jumps to the second box**. Reload again, and it jumps to the third. Reload yet again, and no checkboxes are left checked.

If I leave out one of the buttons by dropping one of the append calls, it's fine. If I change the buttons to divs or something similar, it's fine. If I replace the dl tag with a div (and get rid of the dt tags), it's fine. But I need both buttons, and the checkboxes have to be in a list for what I'm trying to build.

Does anybody know what's causing this?

Comment: even weirder, i loaded up your html, then checked box 1 then ran your js twice. when i refreshed, the checked box was box 3. i think you've found yourself a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting behaviour. My guess is that this is Firefox's "memorize form field values" mechanism going awry - how and why, I don't know, though.

The problem could of course also be caused by something outside the code you have shown us. Are you 100% sure there are no tricky JQuery routines, other plugins or anything?

The issue certainly merits more research, but in the meantime, try whether `.reset()`ting the form helps. It should bring all the form values back to their predefined state (=unchecked).

Comment: Of course! Firefox remembers form state AND javascript state for cached pages. Thanks for thinking of that. And using the reset event works for my purposes if I call it on the onunload event or Firefox's own pageHide event (if I still want the page to cache). More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching. 

Other browsers remember state differently...though by adding some more complexity to the example above, I was able to get some different weird behavior out of IE. I haven't found similar behavior with Chrome yet.

Answer (score 6):

First off, removing the script results in the expected behavior; however, giving the checkboxes unique names changes the describe/problematic behavior to where it's not so problematic:

```
<dt><label for="a1"><input type="checkbox" id="a1" name="c1"/>one</label></dt>
<dt><label for="a2"><input type="checkbox" id="a2" name="c2"/>two</label></dt>
<dt><label for="a3"><input type="checkbox" id="a3" name="c3"/>three</label></dt>
```

If you check a box and then reload the page, the check is cleared altogether.

Changing `insertBefore` to `insertAfter` fixes the original problem and causes the checkbox selection to act is it normally does after a page refresh.  I'm looking more deeply into the issue now.

Comment: Interesting that insertAfter works, but insertBefore doesn't. +1 for finding that. A jQuery bug?

Comment: It looks like a DOM/Firefox issue. Even if you have a div in the markup prior to the `<dl>` list and use vanilla DOM methods to insert the buttons, the problem still occurs.

Comment: In my case, I only had PHP generated code for these checkboxes - nothing was added to the DOM. If I changed a checkbox state through jquery, Firefox would toggle not the next, but the second checkbox after the one I toggled on reload and keep going through the list on further reloads, each time skipping the next checkbox. Very weird. Setting the names to the same as the IDs fixed it - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: I took your solution, but er.. i hate to include custom markup just to prevent silly behaviours https://developer.mozilla.org/en/how_to_turn_off_form_autocompletion

Answer (score 1):

update: 
use `$('input[type=checkbox]').attr("autocomplete", "off");` to disable firefox's caching of the checkbox value. (i still can't get around the caching by index hypothesis).

i also tried

```
$('.c').before($('<div/>').append(a).append(b));
```

with the same results. it appears that firefox remembers which box is checked based on its index, so when you refresh it's jumping, because the div before the checkboxes isn't made yet.  but that's obviously a guess since really the buttons would be two elements before the checkboxes anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap your list in a form element. Firefox than can work correctly with the checkboxes.

Best regards.